# R: Submit Form then Scrape Results

Tags: r, forms, web-scraping, rvest, rcurl

I'm trying to write code in R that will allow me to submit a query on http://nbawowy.com/ and scrape the resulting data. I'd like to be able to input values for at least the "Select Team", "Select Players On", and "Select Players Off" fields and then submit the form. As an example, if I select the 76ers as my team, and Ben Simmons as the "Player On", the resulting query is found here: http://nbawowy.com/#/z31mjvm5ss. I've tried using the following code, but it provides me with an unknown field names error:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "http://nbawowy.com/#/l0krk654imh"
session <- html_session(url)

form <- html_form(read_html(url))[[1]]

filled_form <- set_values(form,
                      "s2id_autogen1_search" = "76ers",
                      "s2id_autogen2" = "Ben Simmons")

session1<-submit_form(session, filled_form, submit='submit')
```

Since I can't seem to get passed this initial part, I'm looking to the community for some help. I'd ultimately like to navigate the session to the resulting url and scrape the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with your code. If you check the form returned by the website, you will see that not only there are no list elements named `"s2id_autogen1_search"` or `"s2id_autogen2"`, in fact, the whole form is unnamed. Furthermore, what seems like one form in the browser, are, in fact, multiple forms (so the players' names cannot be even entered into the `html_form(read_html(url))[[1]]` element). Get to know the object to which you are trying to set the values with `str(form)`. Alternatively, try to scrape using `RSelenium`.